# Slide animate background color left to right using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make background color animation start from left to right

```css
ul.vert-one{
    margin:0;padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    display:block;
font:bold 16px Helvetica, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;line-height:165%;
width:200px;
}

ul.vert-one li{
    margin:0;padding:0;border-top:1px solid #4D0000;
border-bottom:1px solid white;
}

ul.vert-one li span{display:block;text-decoration:none;color:white;
background:#600;padding:0 0 0 20px;width:180px;}

ul.vert-one li span:hover{
background:yellow url("images/vert-one_arrow.gif") no-repeat 0 9px;}
```

```html
<div style="background:gray">
    <ul class="vert-one" >
  <li>
      <div>
     <span>home</span>
      </div>
     </li>
         <li>
      <div>
      <span>blog</span>
      </div>
     </li>
         </li>
         <li>
      <div>
      <span>About Us</span>
      </div>
     </li>
  
</ul>
</div>
```

So when I do mouse over, I want yellow color start from left to right. As background color.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kye7tdfc/1/)

Comment: You can't animate the 'position' of a background color. What have you tried?

Answer (score 9):

By applying a background gradient to your element, along with a background width of twice the size of your element, you can render it two different colours, by placing two stoppers at 50%.

Then all you need to do is animate the `background-position` property and you have your effect.

Note:

- You have a lost closing `</li>` in your markup that I've removed.
- Remember [browser prefixes for `linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient#Browser_compatibility)

```css
ul.vert-one li span {
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
    background-size: 200% 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #600 50%, yellow 50%);
    transition: background-position 1s;
    padding:0 0 0 20px;
    width:180px;
}
ul.vert-one li span:hover {
    background-position: -100% 0;
}
ul.vert-one { margin:0; padding:0; list-style-type:none; display:block; font:bold 16px Helvetica, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;   }
ul.vert-one li { margin:0; padding:0; border-top:1px solid #4D0000; border-bottom:1px solid white;}
```

```html
<div style="background:gray">
    <ul class="vert-one">
        <li><div><span>home</span></div></li>
        <li><div><span>blog</span></div></li>
        <li><div><span>About Us</span></div></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Another solution would be using pseudo elements, like `:after`. [Have a look at this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vc9Luzem/). I did remove some unnecessary markup. And if those menu items are meant to be links, you should use the `<a>` tag for that.

```css
ul.vert-one {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    display: block;
    font: bold 16px Helvetica, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height:165%;
    width:200px;
}

ul.vert-one li {
    position: relative;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border-top:1px solid #4D0000;
    border-bottom:1px solid white;
    z-index: 5;
    padding: 0 0 0 20px;
    color:white;
    background:#600;
    width: 180px;
}

ul.vert-one li span {
    position: relative;
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    z-index: 10;
}

ul.vert-one li:after {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 0;
    color: #fff;
    height: 100%;
    background: yellow;
    opacity: 0;
}

ul.vert-one li:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 500ms;
    -webkit-transition: 500ms;
}
```

```html
    <div style="background:gray">
        <ul class="vert-one">
            <li>
                 <span>home</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                 <span>blog</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                 <span>About Us</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -3):

Insert this in your

```
<div class="mybgd" style="background:gray">
```

Insert this in your CSS

```
.mybgd { width: 100%; height:100%; margin-right: 200px; float: left; }
```